# date time format value -

Tags: javascript, flutter, datetime

In flutter getting value but how to convert this in date format

```
print("day:" + day.toString());
print("month" + month.toString());
print("year" +year.toString());
```

getting this value:

> day:7
> I/flutter (12167): month10
> I/flutter (12167): year1993

year value format as this - **"1993-10-07"**. Now, how to convert the value into date-time format and show in this type of date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String formatteddate="${year.toString()}-${month.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}-${day.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}"
```

Comment: sure @Morbius Black.

Comment: newpaydate = (year.toString() + "-" + month.toString() + "-" + day.toString()) as DateTime;

    DateTime now = newpaydate;
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy MM d').format(now);
   // datetime=formattedDate;
    print("formattedDate" + formattedDate);

Comment: getting error of "DateFormat"  in String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy MM d').format(now);

Comment: any library need to import not giving any suggestion

Comment: sorry about ,that my mistake i  have update the answer install intl package @s.j

Comment: int now = day+month+year;
     
    //DateTime now = newpaydate;
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy MM d').format(now); getting error of now but when i convert this in date it again gives errror not supported

Comment: DateTime now = (String.fromCharCode(day) + String.fromCharCode(month) + String.fromCharCode(year)) as DateTime;


    //DateTime now = newpaydate;
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy MM d').format(now);

Comment: if I cast as DateTime; getting an error whenever run code of typecast DateTime.

Comment: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast.  getting  this error every time.

Comment: day:7
I/flutter (12167): month10
I/flutter (12167): year1993   as i shared in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222064/discussion-between-s-j-and-morbius-black).